# Should I downgrade Python 3.5 to 3.4?

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, mezzanine, python-3.5

I just installed Python 3.5 and created a virtual environment with it. Installed Mezzanine (Django CMS) and tried to run the manage.py file and migrate and syncdb etc.

I've been getting constant errors with 3.5 and I think the reason is that the 3.5 have changed some things that Mezzanine depends on.

Is it a good idea to downgrade 3.5 to 3.4? Or will I have more problems when upgrading later if I don't adapt to the changes now. Maybe a very fuzzy question, but I come from 2.7 and I think a lot have changed.

I don't know what to do :)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: HTMLParser error (no module named 'markupbase') e.g.

Comment: The [documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#dependencies) states only Python 2.7 and 3.3 are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, yes, it is probably best to downgrade to Python 3.4. With Django 1.8, the current release of Django, Python 3.5 is not officially supported.

The 1.9 release of Django will officially support Python 3.5, but that is not a guarantee that your 3rd party libraries will as well. Ensuring that will likely come down to a matter of testing, and checking the compatibility of each of your 3rd party apps.

**EDIT:** As noted by knbk, Django 1.8.6 did add official support for Python 3.5. However, this does not invalidate the possibility that your other libraries may not yet support Python 3.5.

Comment: Official support for 3.5 has been added to 1.8 as well, as shown in the [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Comment: Ah, yes, it was added as of 1.8.6 specifically. (https://github.com/django/django/commit/d27085b02d58ecf8b72e7189b6a5feaf634ec977)

Answer (score 0):

If you use postgres, then yes, downgrade since [psycopg2 doesn't support 3.5](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html)

> The current psycopg2 implementation supports:
>
> - Python 2 versions from 2.5 to 2.7
> - Python 3 versions from 3.1 to 3.4
> - PostgreSQL versions from 7.4 to 9.4

Other than that it is really based on your own opinion and what other frameworks you use and what they support. It will also depend on your django version you use, remembering that Django 2.0 will drop support for python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

There is a known [bug](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/148) with virtualenv and using 3.x python. The best solution is to downgrade virtualenv to a version less than 12.04. In the bug report the suggested version to use virtualenv version 12.0.2 if you want to use python 3.x. This information was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021877/4708186